# Gas price data from GETH

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ether, geth-debugging, goethe

I am able to get gas price data as follows from some oracles (i.e., ethgasstation.info, etherscan.io):

```
{  
   "fast":50.0,
   "fastest":200.0,
   "safeLow":10.0,
   "average":20.0,
   "block_time":13.942307692307692,
   "blockNum":7403346,
   "speed":0.7090284960673774,
   "safeLowWait":13.4,
   "avgWait":1.8,
   "fastWait":0.5,
   "fastestWait":0.5
}
```

Is there a way to get similar information (including any other gas info) directly from Geth?

From [Geth documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) I tried some commands especially related to `Gas Price Oracle Options` and also the [curl](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gasprice) that throws errors as follows:

[image: geth] 
[image: curl]

When I run `geth` with or without options, the results are as follows, probably they are the current network status.

I am new to this and pretty sure I am missing something! Any clue is appreciated.

[image: geth with options]
[image: geth without options]

Answer (score 4):

You can try to get pending transactions and calculate an average amount of gasprice.

```
pending_transactions = web3.provider.make_request("parity_pendingTransactions", [])
gas_prices = []
for tx in pending_transactions["result"[:10]]:
    gas_prices.append(int((tx["gasPrice"]),16))

print("Average:")
print("-"*80)
print("gasPrice: ", statistics.mean(gas_prices))
```

Related article (subheader *Estimating Gas*):

https://www.quiknode.io/guides/web3-sdks/estimating-gas-price-using-pending-transactions-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the [`eth_gasPrice`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gasprice) RPC call. From the docs:

> Returns the current price per gas in wei.

Comment: Thank you @shane, I just updated the question with few more queries after your post. Could you please provide me some hint?

Comment: Hmmm. I would think that that should work. Maybe you can try reaching out to the Geth team on their discord channel. I am not sure of the answer.